# Resharper Current Line Expression background color

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

İn Version 2017.3 there is a cool feature called Current Line Expression, i have a problem with the "Dark with light editor" and "Dark" themes of visual studio 2017 , as you can see in the attached image, Resharper is using a very dark red colour in the text, which makes it hard to read when the background is black .

[image]

Is there any way i can change the background colour or the text colour ?

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed already in the latest update (v.2017.3.1) which I've got today (December, 27th).

The background color on Dark Theme has certainly changed to a brighter color which now effectively makes the values much easier to read.

[image: Current line expression background color]

I haven't found any direct reference to this issue on the release notes, though.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/12/22/resharper-ultimate-2017-3-1-bugfix-available/
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=in:ReSharper%20Fix%20version:%202017.3.1%20

So, the advice would be, update to 2017.3.1 ASAP.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response.
i did notice today that the issue has been resolved in the "Dark" theme, however it is not solved in "Dark With Light Editor" theme . 

I will try to edit the editor my self in the Dark theme and see what happens . 

Thank you .